# emit não funcionando

Tags: vue.js

código

pai:

```
<template>
  <div class="col-6">   
    <span @changeTitle="changeTitle($event)"> table -[{{title}}]</span><br>
    <ModalRegistert />

  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import ModalRegister from './ModalRegister';

  export default {
    data: () => ({
      title: "asdf"
     }),
    methods: {
      changeTitle: function(newTitle) {
        this.title = newTitle,
        console.log("updateTitle - table");
      }
    },
    components: {
      ModalRegister
    }
  }
</script>
```

filho:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <span>modal - [{{title}}]</span>
    <v-btn x-small @click="changeTitle"> add </v-btn><br>
  </div>
</template>


<script>
  export default {
    data: () => ({
      title: "asdf"
    }),

    methods: {
      changeTitle() {
        console.log("01 - register");
        this.title = "new"
        this.$emit('changeTitle', "title")
      }
    },
  }
</script>
```

Mas ele apenas imprime no log o register(filho), e não altera  o título do pai

Answer (score 0):

Bom dia amigo,

Faça a seguinte alteração no componente pai.

```
<span @changeTitle="changeTitle(title = $event)"> table -[{{title}}]</span><br>
```

Faça a seguinte alteração no componente filho:

```
this.$emit('changeTitle', this.title)
```

Neste link tem um exemplo do emit, de forma bem simples. 
https://codesandbox.io/embed/laughing-matsumoto-pczvf

Também peguei teu componente e mudei um pouco para funcionar o $emit. Fiz um exemplo dele aqui:
https://codesandbox.io/embed/vue-template-r5qxz

Espero que te ajude.
Abraço!